# Why did Stack Overflow's 2010 survey not include Python in its choices for technologies?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-developer-survey

In the 2010 survey I took today there was no choice for Python under "Which technologies do you use...". I see **16,028 Python** tagged questions on SO currently and only **6,556 Ruby** tagged questions and Ruby is on the list, so why wouldn't they include Python when it's three times as important to the site's traffic, according to the audience?

Comment: **[subjective]** is currently at 6190. You're not saying tag count equates to an indication of its importance to the site are you?

Comment: yeah, I'm pretty sure that if more people talk about thing A than thing B, than thing A is more important than thing B. I'm also saying that the entire scientific comunity uses Python, including NASA, so maybe SO cares about Python.

Comment: http://langpop.com/ is one site which gives fairly neutral objective numbers on language popularity as measured by multiple verifiable real-world metrics.

Comment: @smci - thanks, that's interesting.

Comment: ...and as of 4/2011 it shows that Python was ~40% more widespread than Ruby on most metrics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can certainly look at the activity per tag, but we're more interested in how this correlates with the technologies in the survey.

To expand on [Æther's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35037/why-does-stack-overflows-recent-survey-not-include-python-in-its-choices-for-tec/35038#35038), there is little (if any) interest in Python from an advertising perspective. Plus, there don't seem to be too many commercial products available.

As for Ruby/Rails.. for whatever reason *cough*fad*cough*, it's pretty hot and there's a lot of interest from advertisers.

Comment: Of course it isn't commercial, much of the entire Python ecosphere is avowedly open-source, other than some proprietary IDEs. That's very much an intentional choice, and a reaction to the two decades of suck that was "Enterprise Java". (SO advertising salespeople) please don't conflate "commercial products" with "technologies" - only bad marketing types do that. If there's no market for selling an underperforming bloated commercial tool because there are better free open-source alternatives, that's always a positive, never a negative. Unless you're an advertising salesperson.

Comment: *"[In 2010" there is little (if any) interest in Python from an advertising perspective"* Err, so what? I'm sure if we rewound the clock to the early 1980s, COBOL and PL/1 would be king. Where are they now...?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps SO's advertising clients don't care as much about Python as Ruby.

There is an "other" section though:

> Please list any additional technologies you actively use: ___________________